# How to add last field of arrays together

Tags: javascript, arrays, sum

I'm trying to take this array, and add each of the last fields together ex: 22, 44, 88, 2, 6, 66, 11 and then put it into one variable using javascript. Also I would like to put the amount of products in the array into a different variable. Does anyone know a simple way to do this? Would I use a loop?

```
let products = [
    ["product1", "Small Widget", "159753", 33, 22],
    ["product2", "Medium Widget", "258456", 55, 44],
    ["product3", "Large Widget", "753951", 77, 88],
    ["product4", "Not a Widget", "852654", 11, 2],
    ["product5", "Could be a Widget", "654456", 99, 6],
    ["product6", "Ultimate Widget", "321456", 111, 66],
    ["product7", "Jumbo Small Medium Widget", "987456", 88, 11]
];
```

Comment: In the future, attempt to solve the problem and only ask when stuck. This might be closed due to zero attempts at solving.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let products = [
    ["product1", "Small Widget", "159753", 33, 22],
    ["product2", "Medium Widget", "258456", 55, 44],
    ["product3", "Large Widget", "753951", 77, 88],
    ["product4", "Not a Widget", "852654", 11, 2],
    ["product5", "Could be a Widget", "654456", 99, 6],
    ["product6", "Ultimate Widget", "321456", 111, 66],
    ["product7", "Jumbo Small Medium Widget", "987456", 88, 11]
];


let sum = 0
products.forEach(product=>{
  sum += product[product.length -1]
})

console.log(sum)


let product_of_elements = 1
products.forEach(product=>{
  product_of_elements *= product[product.length -1]
})

console.log(product_of_elements)
```

In the end, `sum` variable will contain the sum of all the last elements, and `product_of_elements` variable will contain their products.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to loop. This will help you see how to access different parts of the arrays.

```js
let products = [
    ["product1", "Small Widget", "159753", 33, 22],
    ["product2", "Medium Widget", "258456", 55, 44],
    ["product3", "Large Widget", "753951", 77, 88],
    ["product4", "Not a Widget", "852654", 11, 2],
    ["product5", "Could be a Widget", "654456", 99, 6],
    ["product6", "Ultimate Widget", "321456", 111, 66],
    ["product7", "Jumbo Small Medium Widget", "987456", 88, 11]
];

// how many items in products? (how many times to loop.)
console.log(products.length);

// get the first item (array).
console.log(products[0]);

// get the 4th item ([3]) in the 1st array ([0]).
console.log(products[0][3]);
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution

```
const products = [
    ["product1", "Small Widget", "159753", 33, 22],
    ["product2", "Medium Widget", "258456", 55, 44],
    ["product3", "Large Widget", "753951", 77, 88],
    ["product4", "Not a Widget", "852654", 11, 2],
    ["product5", "Could be a Widget", "654456", 99, 6],
    ["product6", "Ultimate Widget", "321456", 111, 66],
    ["product7", "Jumbo Small Medium Widget", "987456", 88, 11]
];

let sum = 0;
const productItems = [];

products.forEach((product) => {
    const len = product.length;
    sum += product[len - 1]; // Add last number
    productItems.push(product[1]); // Add product name to an array
})

console.log(sum);
console.log(productItems);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    You can run a for of loop on the products array and since its the last element you are trying to pick, a simple array.pop will help   
    
        let products = [
  ["product1", "Small Widget", "159753", 33, 22],
  ["product2", "Medium Widget", "258456", 55, 44],
  ["product3", "Large Widget", "753951", 77, 88],
  ["product4", "Not a Widget", "852654", 11, 2],
  ["product5", "Could be a Widget", "654456", 99, 6],
  ["product6", "Ultimate Widget", "321456", 111, 66],
  ["product7", "Jumbo Small Medium Widget", "987456", 88, 11],
];

function addLastitem(products) {
  let sum = 0;
  for (let arrItem of products) {
    sum = sum + arrItem.pop();
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const list = [22, 44, 88, 2, 6, 66, 11]
products.map((item, index) => [...item, list[index]])
```